# Changing the duration of a pulse in PSPICE

Tags: simulation

I am trying to simulate lightning in PSpice using an exponential voltage source (VEXP). The duration of the lightning pulse is required to be in the 110-120 microseconds range with peak voltage = 400V. The one that I am getting, however, reaches nearly 800 microseconds. I've been randomly changing parameters on the source but they don't seem to affect pulse duration. Any input from you guys would be much appreciated?
Rise time (time till peak) = 40 microseconds (measured from 0)
Decay time (50% of peak) = 120 microseconds (measured from 0)
[image: VEXP]
[image: Simulation output]

Comment: Don't twiddle around the edges. Cut all 4 of the first parameters by a factor of 2. See what happens.

Answer (score 2):

An example of usage is:

VLIGHT Node1 Node2 EXP(0V 400V 0uS 20uS 40uS 20uS)

with the format EXP( V1 V2 [Td1 [Tau1 [Td2 [Tau2]]]])

The EXP form causes the the voltage to be V1 for the first TD1 seconds, then the voltage decays exponentially from V1 to V2 with time constant Tau1.  The delay lasts Td2-Td1 seconds.  Then the voltage decays from V2 back to V1 with time constant of Tau2.

You state that the pulse duration must exist for 110-120 us but you don't define **what** the definition of pulse duration is.  Is it \$e^{-1}\$? or is it 90% -> 10% ?.  When dealing with exponentials, 6 time constants is considered to be fully settled.  So in your case if Tau1 = Tau2 and you want it fully settled then Tau1=Tau2=10 uS -> 60 us to settle up and 60 us to settle down for a total of 120 us.